# Eclipse run test one by one

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing

I'm looking for a way to run a only a one test case in my test class from the some kind of test methods list. 
For example, when I run a whole batch of test methods, the failure list appears like that:
[image]

And I can right-click on the appropriate test method and re-run it without a running a whole batch. But in the next i'm getting the error list, that consists of only that method:

[image]

At that point it would be nice to run the another test method as only one, without running a whole batch. Is there a way in Eclipse to get the list of my test methods where it's would be possible to choose the method to run?

Comment: In the JUnit view toolbar there is a _Test Run History..._ button/drop-down where you can go back to the test result of a previous run without rerunning it. You can also right-click on the test method to run this method only: in the Java editor, in _Outline_ view of the Java editor, in the _Package Explorer_, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! All of the methods work fine!

Answer (score 0):

In the ***JUnit* view toolbar** there is a ***Test Run History...*** button/drop-down where you can go back to the test result of a previous run without rerunning it.

In addition, you can also **right-click on a test method** to run this method only: for example in the Java editor, in *Outline* view of the Java editor, in the *Package Explorer* or in the *Project Explorer*.